# Booting Sequence for a multi-module Spring Boot gradle Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, spring-web

I have a mutli-module gradle spring boot project that I would like to define the order in which the modules are run as one depends on the other for it's environment variables. These would be run in the cloud so, I need a way to make them run dynamically in my specified order. Or, do I have to break them up?

I'm using Spring Cloud Config to provide the properties for Eureka Server. This would be run in Heroku cloud platform. Thanks!

Comment: when you say "order in which the modules are run" do you mean they order they are built (with Gradle), or do you mean the order the resulting artifacts are run?

Comment: @codefinger, I mean the order in which the resulting artifacts are run. If it's possible to achieve this using Gradle, that'll will be great but, how would I implement that in a cloud environment? Even though it's a multi-module project, I have to run them individually starting with the Config-Server then Eureka Server.